# How to create a tree in the vscode activity bar with rest api data

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am new to javascript and I was struct at creating a treeview in vscode.

While creating treeview If I pass JSON directly to the tree It creates a tree but when I pass the data by calling the rest API the tree Is not created.

This is because before the data is retrieved from the rest api the empty data variable has been passed to the tree.

How to solve this?

Thanks in Advance

```
class name {
gettreeItem(element){
//code
}

getChildren(element) {
if(element){
//some code here
}else{
return Promise.resolve(this.getDeps(restcall()))
}

restcall(){
var options = { 
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'url',
        headers: 
          { 
            Authorization :'Basic '+ Buffer.from('uid:pas').toString('base64') 
          } 
    };
return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        request.get(options,function(err, resp, body){
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                return resolve(JSON.parse(body));
            }
})
)
}
getDeps(JsonData){
//But here the Json Data is empty beacuse this function is called before the data is retrived from the rest api
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you already have working prototype that can generate the tree view. Now, once you have fetch the data from REST call, after that you have to refresh the tree view.

```
private _onDidChangeTreeData: EventEmitter<X | undefined> = new EventEmitter<X | undefined>();
readonly onDidChangeTreeData: Event<X | undefined> = this._onDidChangeTreeData.event;

refresh(): void {
    this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire(undefined);
}
```

Replace the X with your data type and once your data fetch is complete call the refresh method that we made above. This will solve your issue.